# How to preprocess htseq counts for gene expression (TCGA)

Tags: gene-expression, tcga

I want to prepare a matrix of gene expression to analyse TCGA LAML data.

The required data is available at [TCGA LAML - Gene expression quantification](https://gdc-portal.nci.nih.gov/search/s?facetTab=files&filters=%7B%22op%22:%22and%22,%22content%22:%5B%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22cases.project.program.name%22,%22value%22:%5B%22TCGA%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22cases.project.primary_site%22,%22value%22:%5B%22Bone%20Marrow%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22cases.project.project_id%22,%22value%22:%5B%22TCGA-LAML%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22cases.project.disease_type%22,%22value%22:%5B%22Acute%20Myeloid%20Leukemia%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22files.data_category%22,%22value%22:%5B%22Transcriptome%20Profiling%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22files.experimental_strategy%22,%22value%22:%5B%22RNA-Seq%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22files.analysis.workflow_type%22,%22value%22:%5B%22HTSeq%20-%20Counts%22%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22op%22:%22in%22,%22content%22:%7B%22field%22:%22files.data_type%22,%22value%22:%5B%22Gene%20Expression%20Quantification%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D).

The following is an example of the kind of data retrieved from the TCGA data portal:

```
ENSG00000000003.13  9
ENSG00000000005.5   1
ENSG00000000419.11  661
ENSG00000000457.12  1434
ENSG00000000460.15  1211
ENSG00000000938.11  405
ENSG00000000971.14  251
ENSG00000001036.12  786
ENSG00000001084.9   4423
ENSG00000001167.13  5038
ENSG00000001460.16  246
ENSG00000001461.15  2773
ENSG00000001497.15  1932
ENSG00000001561.6   1693
ENSG00000001617.10  55
ENSG00000001626.13  8
ENSG00000001629.8   4629
```

Each row displays, for each gene, the quantification of read counts by the htseq tool.

My question is, how do I have to preprocess the data (e.g. regarding gene length) before using data for subsequent analysis?

In this case I will not consider normalisation (such as loess) and batch effects removal (e.g. with combat).

Comment: This entirely depends on the type of subsequent analysis so the question isn’t really answerable without more information. However, in general I recommend you [familiarise yourself with a standard RNA-seq analysis workflow](https://f1000research.com/articles/4-1070/v2).